# Remove item from array based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter all the words in array and remove the ones that has more or less than four characters. Then I want to check if the words filtered contains "6", if it's true I'll remove it from the array.

The problem is that I put four "6666" in the array to test if it's removing, but it only removes 3. How can I put a dynamically number to remove correctly?

```
let textA = "6666 6666 6666 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
        
        
       const arr1 = textA.split(" ");  
    
    const newArray = arr1.filter(function(element) { 
        return element.length === 4;
    });
    
    
    for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        if (newArray[i].includes("6")){
            newArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `filter` for the first part and a loop for the second?

Comment: Knowledge limitation :|

Comment: so, it's solved?

Comment: `splice` modifies the array so the second `6666` is skipped because it's now in the `0` position and your index is `1`

Comment: Actually it's not. The problem is that if put for example six "6666" in the array, the code won't remove all of them.

Comment: @Kali If you're comfortable moving away from `splice()` for this task, you can actually get exactly what you're looking for in a single line using split and then the `filter()` method: `textA.split(' ').filter(word => word.length === 4 && !word.includes('6'))`. See it in action in my solution below.

Comment: @chazsolo but i have to make it with a dynamically number, the array I give it's an example, I have to create this behavior on the code in a bigger array where I can't count manually the "6666"

Comment: It doesn't matter the number you are looking for, or how many of them there are - I only point out that `splice` will modify the array you are looping over which is causing your problem. As the answers suggest, removing what you are looking for during the initial filter is the best way to go.

Comment: @Kali You can make your loop work by looping backwards, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Kali, Please add few more test cases or examples to understand your question better and cover all the scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect place to use `split()` and `filter()`. We can do both filters in one line:

```js
let textA = "6666 6666 6666 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";

const newArray = textA.split(' ').filter(word => word.length === 4 && !word.includes('6'))

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to do both steps at once.

```js
let textA = "6666 6666 6666 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
const arr1 = textA.split(" ");
const newArray = arr1.filter(function(element) {
  return element.length === 4 && !element.includes('6');
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Your `for` loop did not work properly because removing an element while iterating forward shifts all the next elements one index down, so you skip an element each time. Looping backwards or decrementing the index after removing will fix this.

```js
let textA = "6666 6666 6666 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
const arr1 = textA.split(" ");
const newArray = arr1.filter(function(element) {
  return element.length === 4;
});
for (let i = newArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (newArray[i].includes("6")) {
    newArray.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(newArray);
```